# Excel/OLAP and HTTP Basic Authorization - Can Excel Remember That It Has Logged In?

Tags: java, excel, http, authentication, activepivot

We are trying to enable a custom credential handling layer to our
ActivePivot tomcat servlet by intercepting incoming requests to
the Cube and authenticating them as needed using a Spring Security Filter.  Our system provides
an "API Key" to logged in users if the username and password are
valid and we would like some way of getting Excel to use this key once it has been logged in using HTTP Basic AUthentication.

When entering login credentials into the Excel "Data Connection
Wizard" to connect to the AP Cube, it goes through the normal
procedure of doing a GET on a Cube URL, where we return a
401 (since no API Key is present in the headers) with a
"WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=..."  header, to which it responds
by getting the same URL with an "Authenticate: Basic ..." header
with which we perform a username/password login and get an API
key and actually return the contents for the request.  This is
all good and working as expected.

The question is, can we get Excel to remember that it has
successfully authenticated and just pass the API Key in
the "Authenticate" header in future requests?  So far I have
tried to send the API Key back in an "Authenticate" header in the
response but Excel doesn't seem to notice that.  Is there a
standard way to pass a 'login token' for basic auth to the
client?

This would solve 2 problems on our end: 1) we don't have to do a
login every time a request is made and 2) we don't get double the
number of requests (GET -> 401 -> GET with Auth -> return) since
Excel would know it has already authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

can you have a look at PRE_AUTH_FILTER from spring security:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/preauth.html
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to this article it looks like what I want might be impossible without hacking up a redirect of some sort:

http://www.vc2go.com/2009/11/cookie-based-authentication-does-not-work-with-excel.html

> Problem: Some security expert (I assume) at one of the largest IT companies in the world, figured out that sending cookies on web-requests from Excel is a bad thing. E.g. when you select a URL link in Excel, the resulting request in IE will *never* send any cookies. The request will open up in Internet Explorer fine, but it sucks that the users have to log onto our system for each row they access.
>
> If you based authentication on sessions or cookies, you are basically stuck.